# Debugging performance drop in metal compute shader via Xcode

Tags: debugging, gpu, metal, compute-shader

I've created a metal compute shader sometime back which was taking a frame as texture and arguments as memory pointer.
But later I realized that I could simply pass the frame as buffer pointer and save upon the texture bind call to improve upon the performance. Also, the arguments could be passed as argument list to shader rather than as memory pointers (again to boost performance).

The above change however has resulted in an increase in the shader execution time.
I looked for [references](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/optimizing_performance_with_the_gpu_counters_instrument/reducing_shader_bottlenecks) to how to use counters to identify bottlenecks but I could not locate exactly where to look for ALU Limiter counter or Texture Sample Limiter Counter etc.

Kindly help regarding where I may locate these counters.
Also, what techniques I may use to measure what exactly is taking longer time in my compute shader than before?